# Filter all sheets in a work book based on a checkbox (in Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to filter an entire workbook of templates based off of a checkbox. Each additional sheet in the workbook is created with formulas already. Basically, I have 5 teams. 1 team encompasses all of the others, the other 4 are individual teams. I'm trying to create a process where by clicking the checkbox, all other sheets will filter to only show that team.

Comment: Have you tried using Apps Script? Are you planning on using formulas? Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: You should be able to do this since all sheets are created using formulas. Try the `=FILTER()` function

Comment: `=IF()` & `=FILTER()` function should do the job provide sample sheet for better understanding